# Illegal in PHP: Is there an OOP design reason?

Tags: php, object-oriented-design, interfaces

The below interface inheritance is illegal in PHP, but I think it would be fairly useful in real life. Is there an actual antipattern or documented problem with the below design, that PHP is protecting me from?

```
<?php

/**
 * Marker interface
 */
interface IConfig {}

/**
 * An api sdk tool
 */
interface IApi
{
    public __construct(IConfig $cfg);
}

/**
 * Api configuration specific to http
 */
interface IHttpConfig extends IConfig
{
    public getSomeNiceHttpSpecificFeature();
}

/**
 * Illegal, but would be really nice to have.
 * Is this not allowed by design?
 */
interface IHttpApi extends IApi
{
    /**
     * This constructor must have -exactly- the same
     * signature as IApi, even though its first argument
     * is a subtype of the parent interface's required
     * constructor parameter.
     */
    public __construct(IHttpConfig $cfg);

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's ignore for a second that the method in question is `__construct` and call it `frobnicate`. Now suppose you have an object `api` implementing `IHttpApi`, and an object `config` implementing `IHttpConfig`. Clearly, this code fits the interface:

```
$api->frobnicate($config)
```

But let's suppose we upcast `api` to `IApi`, for example passing it to `function frobnicateTwice(IApi $api)`. Now in that function, `frobnicate` is called, and since it only deals with `IApi`, it may perform a call such as `$api->frobnicate(new SpecificConfig(...))` where `SpecificConfig` implements `IConfig` but not `IHttpConfig`. At no point anyone did anything unsavory with types, yet `IHttpApi::frobnicate` got a `SpecificConfig` where it expected a `IHttpConfig`.

This is no good. We don't want to prohibit upcasting, we want subtyping, and we clearly want multiple classes implementing an interface. So the only sensible option is to prohibit a subtype method requiring *more specific* types for parameters. (A similar problem occurs when you want to *return* a more *general* type.)

Formally, you've walked into a classic trap surrounding polymorphism, [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). Not all occurrences of a type `T` can be replaced by a subtype `U`. Conversely, not all occurrences of a type `T` can be replaces by a *supertype* `S`. Careful consideration (or better yet, strict application of type theory) is necessary.

Coming back to `__construct`: Since AFAIK you can't exactly instantiate an interface, only a concrete implementer, this may seem like a pointless restriction (it's never going to get called through an interface). But in that case, why include `__construct` in the interface to begin with? Regardless, it would be of little use to special-case `__construct` here.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, this follows directly from the [Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). When you override a method, the return type can become more specific, while types of arguments must stay the same or can become more general.

This is more obvious with methods other than `__construct`. Consider:

```
class Vehicle {}
class Car extends Vehicle {}
class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {}

class Driver {
    public drive(Vehicle $v) { ... }
}
class CarDriver extends Driver {
    public drive(Car $c) { ... }
}
```

A `CarDriver` is a `Driver`, so a `CarDriver` instance must be able to do *anything* that a `Driver` can. Including driving `Motorcycles`, because it's just a `Vehicle`. But the argument type for `drive` says that a `CarDriver` can only drive `Car`s – a contradiction: `CarDriver` *can't* be a proper subclass of `Driver`.

The reverse makes more sense:

```
class CarDriver {
    public drive(Car $c) { ... }
}
class MultiTalentedDriver extends CarDriver {
    public drive(Vehicle $v) { ... }
}
```

A `CarDriver` can only drive `Car`s. A `MultiTalentedDriver` can also drive `Car`s, because a `Car` is just a `Vehicle`. Therefore, `MultiTalentedDriver` is a proper subclass of `CarDriver`.

In your example, any `IApi` can be constructed with an `IConfig`. If `IHttpApi` is a subtype of `IApi`, we must be able to construct an `IHttpApi` using any `IConfig` instance – but it only accepts `IHttpConfig`. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Not all drivers can drive both cars and motorcycles...

Comment: @faif: In this particular abstraction, they not only can, they must. Because, as you can see, a `Driver` can drive any `Vehicle`, and since both `Car` and `Motorcycle` extends `Vehicle`, all `Driver`s must be able to handle both.